# Java TextArea update

Tags: java, textarea, awt, updates

```
for (do something in) {
TextArea.append("Text here");
//break for one second
}
```

My question is how can i break for one second and display it directly on the textarea and not everything on the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pausing execution for one second could be done with

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

But you should catch the possible `InterruptedException`

```
try
{
  Thread.sleep(1000);
}
catch(InterruptedException e)
{
 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

You should also make changes to GUI components via

```
 EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
  public void run()
  { 
    //make gui change here
  }
 });
```

This updates it from the AWT GUI Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

Comment: I know that you can use that but then it still display it all on the same time

Comment: Then I'm assuming you have a large block of text in `TextArea.append("Text here");`.  In that case you'll need to manually break the text up into blocks and output each block once per loop.

Comment: You need to give the JVM control of the EDT so it can update the GUI.

Comment: If you put the append into an invokeLater(), does that help?

Answer (score 0):

For break only one second you have to use sleep(1000) method of Thread class and for achieving multithreading you have to override the run method and extend the Thread class

Answer (score 0):

It may be displaying all at once if your TextArea.append calls are not happening in the swing thread. The block below requests that the swing thread execute the code in the runnable blocking the current thread until it is complete. We then do our 1 second sleep

```
    final JTextArea someArea = new JTextArea();

    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                someArea.append("Some text");
            }
        });
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```